# C# Syncing data between SQLite and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sqlite, synchronization

I'm designing a small piece of software for a company. Basically, they need to manage a large list of items. Edit, delete, and so on. Basically, I'm storing the data INITIALLY in SQLite locally on their computer. Once they get done modifying the "list" items, they will need to be synced over to the SQL Server database on the production server.

What would be the most reliable way to sync data between the databases? I'm also going to be storing small images for each item. I'm estimating anywhere between 1000~5000+ items within the first month.

Can I do this all via SQL? Or do I need to convert the SQLite database to another format? Or pull the data from the SQLITE DB, and manually sync it?

Comment: What is the reason you want to use SQLite? Can't you store it in the MSSQL database, just in a different set of tables?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using SQL Server Compact Edition v4 (on .NET 4) instead??

It would support T-SQL front to end, and it's just as easily deployable as SQLite. It's "in-proc", e.g. just a fine DLL's to include in your project, it stores everything inside a single `.sdf` file, it needs no server install, no runtime other than .NET 4......

See:

- [Here Comas SQL Server CE 4](http://robtiffany.com/sql-server-compact/here-comes-sql-server-compact-4-0)
- [ScottGU: VS 2010 SP1 and SQL Server CE 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx)
- [SQL Server CE Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the Sync Framework, it looks like it is exactly the kind of problem it is supposed to solve.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902854.aspx

Comment: One way or another it will. AFAIK there is not builtin support but there is an open-source project for that: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqliteclientsyn/